# ROS2 message_filters: Is it a bug in The Latest Time synchronizer?

Tags: ros2, message-filters

In `message_filters/include/message_filters/sync_policies/latest_time.h`

`rates_` is array of `struct` Rate. I thought that its index corresponds to the channel index. But its initialization in function `initialize_rate()` doesn't put the new `struct` (including alphas and prev) to index `i`. Instead `push_back` is used. As a result, the index of `rates_` seems to represent the order of arrival of the first message of each channel. This appears confusing to me. The policy uses `rates_[i]` afterwards to calculate statistics of channel i. But its initialization depends on the order of messages, which is a runtime behaviour. How can I properly set the alphas for each channel?

Here is the source code of `initialize_rate()`:

```
template<int i>
  void initialize_rate()
  {
    if (rate_configs_.size() > 0U) {
      double rate_ema_alpha{Rate::DEFAULT_RATE_EMA_ALPHA};
      double error_ema_alpha{Rate::DEFAULT_ERROR_EMA_ALPHA};
      double rate_step_change_margin_factor{Rate::DEFAULT_MARGIN_FACTOR};
      if (rate_configs_.size() == RealTypeCount::value) {
        std::tie (
          rate_ema_alpha,
          error_ema_alpha,
          rate_step_change_margin_factor) = rate_configs_[i];
      } else if (rate_configs_.size() == 1U) {
        std::tie (
          rate_ema_alpha,
          error_ema_alpha,
          rate_step_change_margin_factor) = rate_configs_[0U];
      }
      rates_.push_back(
        Rate(
          ros_clock_->now(),
          rate_ema_alpha,
          error_ema_alpha,
          rate_step_change_margin_factor));
    } else {
      rates_.push_back(Rate(ros_clock_->now()));
    }
  }
```